# Android dynamic library load vs. LoadLibrary

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I embed libabc.so inside my app it works fine with
`System.LoadLibrary("abc");`

However, when I move libabc.so to /system/lib/ and I try to load it with
`System.Load("/system/lib/libabc.so");` I get the following linker error in logcat:

> 06-12 04:42:09.864: D/dalvikvm(17630): Trying to load lib /system/lib/libabc.so 0x4254afd8
>
> **06-12 04:42:09.869: E/linker(17630): "libabc.so": ignoring 2-entry DT_PREINIT_ARRAY in shared library!**
>
> 06-12 04:42:09.869: D/dalvikvm(17630): Added shared lib /system/lib/libabc.so 0x4254afd8
>
> 06-12 04:42:09.869: D/dalvikvm(17630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libabc.so 0x4254afd8, skipping init

It actually loads my library but I'm unable to call the exported functions (it tells that native method is not implemented).

Why?

Comment: By the way, when you move `libabc.so` to `/system/lib/`, you can still load it with `System.loadLibrary("abc");`

Comment: Maybe, the app package name has changed?

Comment: No. Same app. Just changing the function and rebuilding. I realized that everything loaded from /data/app-lib/myappname/ is fine but from other places it just doesn't work... why?

Comment: Changing which function? As I wrote, you can use `System.loadLibrary("abc")` to load from `/system/lib/`.

Comment: I know, it does load the library. But I can't call the exported functions. As if they are not implemented. The only thing that work is to load the library from /data/app-lib/myappname/

Comment: **1.** what is your device/Android version? **2.** what does `nm -D libabc.so` show?

Comment: It show the exported functions

`00002bfd T Java_com_john_mytestApp_TestService_myfunc
00002d09 T Java_com_john_mytestApp_TestService_test`

Comment: Please post your Java file `src/com/john/mytestApp/TestService.java`, too. Did you show `nm` output for file you pulled from `/system/lib/`?

Comment: Added the code in the next post. And yes, the nm output was from the library pulled from /system/lib

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {

    static { System.loadLibrary("abc"); }

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    public native long myfunc(String arg);

    public TestService() {
        super("TestService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        runnable.run();
    }

    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            System.out.println(">>> " + myfunc("test"));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this error? I am having same issue.